# Multidimensional Array Find and Update the Value in specific index using php

Tags: php, arrays

I've a following Multidimensional array named $data

```
$data =
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [AllocationPool] => TEST do not USE
        [Quarter] => 2016-Q4
        [Region] => 
        [SubRegion] => 
        [Country] => 
        [typeofrec] => 0
        [TotalAllocations] => 1000
        [TotalTransfersOut] => 0
        [TotalTransfersIn] => 0
        [StartOfAllocation] => 1000
        [ApprovedActivities] => 0
        [AvailableBalance] => 1000
        [TotalApprovedClaims] => 0
        [Balance] => 1000
        [TotalUnApprovedClaims] => 0
        [Exposure] => 1000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [AllocationPool] => TEST do not USE
        [Quarter] => 2016-Q4
        [Region] => 
        [SubRegion] => 
        [Country] => 
        [typeofrec] => 0
        [TotalAllocations] => 0
        [TotalTransfersOut] => 0
        [TotalTransfersIn] => 50
        [StartOfAllocation] => 50
        [ApprovedActivities] => 0
        [AvailableBalance] => 50
        [TotalApprovedClaims] => 0
        [Balance] => 50
        [TotalUnApprovedClaims] => 0
        [Exposure] => 50
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [AllocationPool] => TEST do not USE
        [Quarter] => 2016-Q4
        [Region] => EMEA
        [SubRegion] => 
        [Country] => 
        [typeofrec] => 0
        [TotalAllocations] => 0
        [TotalTransfersOut] => 0
        [TotalTransfersIn] => 25
        [StartOfAllocation] => 25
        [ApprovedActivities] => 0
        [AvailableBalance] => 25
        [TotalApprovedClaims] => 0
        [Balance] => 25
        [TotalUnApprovedClaims] => 0
        [Exposure] => 25
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [AllocationPool] => TEST do not USE
        [Quarter] => 2016-Q4
        [Region] => APJeC
        [SubRegion] => India
        [Country] => India
        [typeofrec] => 0
        [TotalAllocations] => 500
        [TotalTransfersOut] => 0
        [TotalTransfersIn] => 0
        [StartOfAllocation] => 500
        [ApprovedActivities] => 0
        [AvailableBalance] => 500
        [TotalApprovedClaims] => 0
        [Balance] => 500
        [TotalUnApprovedClaims] => 0
        [Exposure] => 500
    )

)
```

and

```
$amount =10;
$index = 2  // selected array index for change
```

The above information i have and i need to update the array with new [AvailableBalance] based on below calculations.

Next i need to get the [AvailableBalance] from the array $index (index 2 )

```
$existing_available = 25;
```

Subtract the $amount from $existing_availablet

$remaining_amount = 15;  // where ($existing_available -  $amount)

Update the  [AvailableBalance] = 15($remaining_amount) using array $index (index2).

so my final array look like below:

```
$data =
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [AllocationPool] => TEST do not USE
        [Quarter] => 2016-Q4
        [Region] => 
        [SubRegion] => 
        [Country] => 
        [typeofrec] => 0
        [TotalAllocations] => 1000
        [TotalTransfersOut] => 0
        [TotalTransfersIn] => 0
        [StartOfAllocation] => 1000
        [ApprovedActivities] => 0
        [AvailableBalance] => 1000
        [TotalApprovedClaims] => 0
        [Balance] => 1000
        [TotalUnApprovedClaims] => 0
        [Exposure] => 1000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [AllocationPool] => TEST do not USE
        [Quarter] => 2016-Q4
        [Region] => 
        [SubRegion] => 
        [Country] => 
        [typeofrec] => 0
        [TotalAllocations] => 0
        [TotalTransfersOut] => 0
        [TotalTransfersIn] => 50
        [StartOfAllocation] => 50
        [ApprovedActivities] => 0
        [AvailableBalance] => 50
        [TotalApprovedClaims] => 0
        [Balance] => 50
        [TotalUnApprovedClaims] => 0
        [Exposure] => 50
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [AllocationPool] => TEST do not USE
        [Quarter] => 2016-Q4
        [Region] => EMEA
        [SubRegion] => 
        [Country] => 
        [typeofrec] => 0
        [TotalAllocations] => 0
        [TotalTransfersOut] => 0
        [TotalTransfersIn] => 25
        [StartOfAllocation] => 25
        [ApprovedActivities] => 0
        [AvailableBalance] => 15      // updated value 
        [TotalApprovedClaims] => 0
        [Balance] => 25
        [TotalUnApprovedClaims] => 0
        [Exposure] => 25
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [AllocationPool] => TEST do not USE
        [Quarter] => 2016-Q4
        [Region] => APJeC
        [SubRegion] => India
        [Country] => India
        [typeofrec] => 0
        [TotalAllocations] => 500
        [TotalTransfersOut] => 0
        [TotalTransfersIn] => 0
        [StartOfAllocation] => 500
        [ApprovedActivities] => 0
        [AvailableBalance] => 500
        [TotalApprovedClaims] => 0
        [Balance] => 500
        [TotalUnApprovedClaims] => 0
        [Exposure] => 500
    )

)
```

Please help me to try this issue.

I am new in php and stack overflow.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you calculate the array index and amount(`$index`, `$amount`) then update the values directly to the array `$data`,

```
$index = 2;
$amount = 10;     
$data[$index]['AvailableBalance'] = $data[$index]['AvailableBalance'] - $amount;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is solution:

```
$index = 2;
$amount = 10;

$existing_available = $data[$index]['AvailableBalance']; //25

$remaining_amount = $existing_available - $amount; //15

//update AvailableBalance of 2nd array
$data[$index]['AvailableBalance'] = $remaining_amount;
```

Working example (other fields are ommitted for simplicity): [CLICK](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cf4c6d8312e46cd08341203682cec3e5f49ef719)

Comment: Sorry but this will not work. It will append new value under index `2`.

Comment: It works ok, I added working example, just click "Execute code" button to see result.

Comment: Oh yes.Previously  it was not working. I think i had missed something. Good luck. +1.

Comment: Instead of declaring a new variable you can update it with a same array values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$index=2;
$amount=10;
foreach($result as $key => $subarray) {
   if($key == $index) { //change this key according to your requirements.
      foreach($subarray as $subkey => $subsubarray) {
         if($subkey == "AvailableBalance") {
             $result[$key][$subkey] = $subsubarray-$amount;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Demo  : https://eval.in/520720

Comment: Sorry this is not working.It will append new value for all under index 2

Comment: have you seen my demo? And also check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Engineer. it's Working Perfectly.

Comment: Why do you want to loop? while you can update the array values values directly based on the index.

Comment: Index `2` is just an example. What if you want to change all the values? With my code you can do this by just removing some `if` conditions.

Comment: The OP wrote that `$index` and `$amount` are values based on calculations, so loop is not required - it can be less efficient in some cases.

Comment: Yes, correct and then one extra looping is also not required and if condition is also not required if he just want to update only 'AvailableBalance' .

Comment: @aslawin OP didn't write that `$index` and `$amount` are values based on calculations. Please read it carefully. OP have this information (just for example) and want to update an array.